# DropDownList Remove "Please select value" from selection upon clicking?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with a disabled initial value "Please select value" and when I click it, it appears again as one of the selections. Is there a way to remove this such that I will only see my items, and not see "Please select value" from the choices of selection?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="115">
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Please select value" Value="" disabled />
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Please select value" Value="" disabled /> here write Text=""

Comment: You want to remove item on Page_Load or OnItemSelected?

Comment: you want to remove that one first change or just click??

Comment: In any way. I just want to remove "please select value" on the selection. But yes i still want it to stay there upon page load so "please select value" will be seen by user. But once user clicks, dropdownlist will show + ANOTHER "please select value.

Comment: In short, there are TWO "Please select value" that appear + my items after I click.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have `autopostback = true`, changing the selection wont take you to the server side where you can remove the first `ListItem`. You can do it on client side using javascript or jQuery.

HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList onclick="changeFun(this);" ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="115">
```

Javascript

```
function changeFun(ddlRole ){         
    if(ddlRole.options[0].text == "Please select value")
        ddlRole.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Aw there's no OnChange in my IntelliSense. :( but thanks for trying!

Comment: You do not always get everything with IntelliSense, give it a try, onchange is javascript event, http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=823

Comment: Thanks! But ddlRole "does not exist in the current context"? I'm missing something.

Comment: ddlRole is id of dropdownlist you have, did you put javascript code in script tags?

Comment: Do you have script and drop down in same page

Comment: Yes I am very sure i put <script> </script> right before '< asp:DropDownList / >'

Comment: Try putting the script tag just before the closing body i.e. '</body>' tag

Comment: Ok no more errors. But still shows "Please select value", cannot be highlighted (since it's disabled), but still shows (after click on dropdown). :(

Comment: It will show when you click it, you have to select some other option to remove it

Comment: To remove it on click you would need onclick instead of onchange, also check my updated code

Comment: It works! Thanks. Now both "Please select value" are gone. Although I'd like the initial value to stay there + my items, it's still better than two "Please select value" showing. :)

Comment: Can I have the same code if I put ddlRole in a GridView? @Adil

Comment: Yes, with little modification, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="115" onclick="removeFirst()">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Please select value" Value="plsselect"  />
    <asp:ListItem>First Item</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Second Item</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in Javascript

```
<script>
    function removeFirst() {
        var select = document.getElementById('<%= ddlRole.ClientID %>');

        for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            if (select.options[i].value == 'plsselect') {
                select.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined" at i < select :( ... Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: It may be because of the wrong client id. Updated my answer